# How can I focus this jquery function to work only with the links I want instead of using any <a> on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The problem I am having is that I have a jquery function set up to run some links that show and hide div boxes. Each one of these boxes has a link in it to hide itself. This functionality works good. However, none of the other links on the page will go where they need to go. If a link is clicked on outside of this system, it just closes any div box that is currently open.

Here is a jsfiddle with the functionality setup, along with an "Extra Link" that should go to Google, but as you will see, it only closes any open div boxes.

Here is the HTML:

```
<a href="#" data-box="box1">Click Me1</a>
<a href="#" data-box="box2">Click Me2</a>
<a href="#" data-box="box3">Click Me3</a>

<div id="hiddendivs">
<div id="box1">
    <a href="#" data-box="box1">Close Me1</a>
</div>

<div id="box2">
    <a href="#" data-box="box2">Close Me2</a>
</div>

 <div id="box3">
    <a href="#" data-box="box3">Close Me3</a>
</div>
</div>


<p class="ptag"><a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Extra Link</a></p>
```

Here is the jquery:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#hiddendivs div').not($('#'+$(this).data("box"))).fadeOut(1000);
$('#' + $(this).data("box")).fadeToggle(1000);
})
```

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/f6g3dnet/7/

Thank you for any help that can be provided.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can target only the links that have a `data-box` attribute:

```
$('a[data-box]').click(function (e) {
e.preventDefault();
$('#hiddendivs div').not($('#'+$(this).data("box"))).fadeOut(1000);
$('#' + $(this).data("box")).fadeToggle(1000);
})
```

http://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/